# In SoundCloud, does streaming a track using the JavaScript SDK increment the playback_count of that track?

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

Does streaming a sound track using SC.stream() increment the playback_count of that track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. any requests to api.soundcloud.com/tracks/TID/stream?client_id=CID

will count as a stream.

same goes for /tracks/TID/download?

Comment: I don't see the counter incremented... could you explain a bit more the syntax you used in this answer ? `SC.stream('/tracks/'+track+'/stream?client_id='+client_id, function(sound) {...}` doesn't work